# cpp inheritance virtual method resolution order

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, overriding, virtual-inheritance

long time reader first time asking here

I'm trying to extend the functionality of an external library by inherit from it.

In the library there is a base class and one that derive from it and implements some low level functions, then there is my implementation derived from the latter.

**Here is a trivial conceptualized code example of the implementation:**

*The base class:*

```
 class A {

    virtual int vf() = 0;

    int get_next(){
        return vf() * 2; 
    } 
};
```

*The derived class:*

```
class B : public A {

    virtual int vf(){
        return 1;
    }

};
```

*My extension to the library:*

```
class C : public B {

    int vf(){
        return B::get_next() + 1;
    }

};
```

**Then I want to call:**

```
C::get_next();
```

But this result in a recursive function call:

```
C::get_next() = A::get_next() -> C::vf() -> A::get_next() -> C::vf() -> A::get_next() -> C::vf() -> A::get_next() -> C::vf() ... and so on
```

What i would like to happen:

```
C::get_next() = A::get_next() -> C::vf() -> A::get_next() -> B::vf() end of call trace
```

Is this possible? I'm doing something wrong in the implementation or hitting some undefined behavior or similar?

Comment: Nope, this is very well defined behavior: infinite recursion. This cannot be done in C++ without redesigning something about these classes, or doing some ugly stuff that would fail a code review.

Comment: How should `A::get_next` decide when to call `C::vf()` vs `B::vf()`?

Comment: This conceptualised whadjamajing doesn't make much sense. Please describe your real problem.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Need to implement CRC on top of Arduino Serials (using template for which serial) one option would be to have class CRC (C in example) inherit from Stream and a reference to Stream/serial object passed at the constructor, then would be like `int C::vf() {return serial_recived_from_constructor.get_next() + 1; };` but this seem pretty ugly and idea was more like a conceptualized question;

Also for reference `virtual int A::vf();` in the reality is `virtual int Stream::read();` of the Arduino Core

Comment: Please show the actual code in the question itself.

Comment: Do you use virtual inheritance anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B::get_next()` still has dynamic dispatch inside that function.

If possible and appropriate, you might **slice** your object:

```
class C : public B {

    int vf() override
    {
        return B(*this).get_next() + 1;
    }
};
```

Comment: @Renat: `A::get_next` is indeed not virtual, but call virtual method.

Comment: I’m going to try this it tomorrow, is this different from using “static_cast<B \*>(this\*).get_next();” ?

Comment: @imwhocodes: I do a (sliced) **copy**. In your version, casting `this` do `B*` does nothing for the dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Doing a copy was not an option, I ended up changing the pattern (going to update the answer later), anyway rating this answer as correct for giving me an actual possible solution, the conciseness and the use of the keywords that put me in the right direction to properly understand the problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you call C::get_next(), it actually calls A::get_next(), which then calls vf() which is overloaded in C. After that B::get_next() is called which again actually just calls A::get_next() resulting in vf() (again overloaded in C not B) call again and repeats. You cannot really achieve what you want with such a confusing design. If you want this kind of call:
`A::get_next() -> C::vf() -> A::get_next() -> B::vf()`

You might have to rewrite some code of that base class like this:

```
int vf(){
  return B::vf() * 2 + 1;
}
```

which basically just ends up as
`A::get_next() -> C::vf() -> B::vf()` and actually makes more sense in C++.

Comment: As I said A and B are inside an external library that I can't edit, also as I tried to explain with the arrows at the end I understood why the recursion happen, my question was about a way to limit the virtual resolution scope of the `int C::vf(){ return B::get_next() + 1; };` having `B::get_next()` using **only B own function overload**, like the splicing suggested by @Jarod42